# JPA: directly mapping collection size to attribute using count?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Class `A` has a one-to-many relationship to `B`. Hence, `A` has an attribute `collectionOfB`.

Is there any way I could map "count B" to single attribute in `A`?

The purpose would be to offer a shortcut to retrieve the number of associated `B`s without loading the entire collection. Sometimes all I need is the count i.e. the collection size. I know I could issue a query against the entity manager that does exactly that. However, seeing it done by the JPA provider thanks to annotations would of course be preferable.

Comment: I don't know of any way to do that. You'll have to just write a COUNT query.

Comment: Just realized that this may be possible using Hibernate formulas (http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-column) if one is willing to give up JPA compliance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem using Hibernate's extra-lazy mapping: http://www.frightanic.com/2010/11/21/extra-lazy-one-to-many-mapping-with-hibernate/

Comment: This is a good approach since it doesn't require much effort. The count query is executed when you invoke size() on the collection.

Answer (score 0):

As far I know, this is not possible.
As you already suggested, run a query to achieve this, which shouldn't be expensive unless you have hundreds of thousands of B objects and you could still cache it and only update each x minutes.

More error prone solution would be to have a stats entity with these kind of numbers.

Comment: The problem I have with writing a query is the way our entities are used. We use Dozer to automatically map them to their respective DTOs (passed back to presentation layer).

Comment: So, when ADto has a field numberOfBs Dozer would call A#getNumberOfBs(). Usually, depending on the JPA annotations in A, data is automatically loaded from the datastore if not yet present in A i.e. lazily. Since we often used partitioned DTOs such as ADto and ASummaryDto the DTO sometimes needs a collection of Bs and sometimes only numberOfBs. Hope I was able to explain this in a comprehendable manner...

Answer (score 0):

Possibly this could be achieved using formulas: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-property